# Ionic - Update a component's variable from another page or component

Tags: ionic3, components

I'm trying to create a custom menu in Ionic3, when the user clicks in that hamburguer icon, it needs to add to the element `#menu`an `open` class, I'm trying to do this with `ngClass`

The problem is that this icon, is outside of my menu component, this icon is in my page `home-user`

[image]

When opened, my menu looks like this next image, so I can't use the default menu from ionic

[image]

So I have my component `menu` that has an variable named `opened`, and this variable decides the class of my menu element

**Menu.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    templateUrl: 'menu.html',
})

export class MenuComponent {

    opened: boolean = true;

    constructor() {
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.opened = !this.opened;
    }
}
```

So when I trigger `toggleMenu()` I change `opened` value

I trigger this function in my component page and works correctly

**Menu.html**

```
<div id="menu" [ngClass]="opened ? 'open' : ''">
    <a class="menu-item" href="#">Sair</a>
    <ion-icon (click)="toggleMenu()" id="toggleMenu" name="close"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

---

**So, whats my problem?**

How can I call this `toggleMenu()` from, for example, my `home-user.html` page, that also has an button and this button should change the value of `opened` variable

---

**What have I tried**

I tried to create a function in my `menu.module.ts` that trigger the `toggleMenu()` function in `menu.ts`

**Menu.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MenuComponent,
    ],
})
export class MenuComponentModule {

    constructor(public menuComponent: MenuComponent) {

    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.menuComponent.toggleMenu()
    }
}
```

But consoling the values, I notice that the value of `opened` is different when calling from component and when calling from my page

Comment: Can you describe what user experience you are trying to get? Its unclear where that menu is and what problem it solves

Comment: @SergeyRudenko, sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to use [`Events`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)  module in ionic.

An event generated by this module propagates globally over whole app.

you can use it like the below.

In **Homepage.ts**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
//skip wrapping component
constructor(public events: Events) {}

onMenuClicked(){
  this.events.publish('toggleMenu')
}
```

In **Menu.ts**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
//skip wrapping component
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('toggleMenu', () => {
    this.opened = !this.opened
  });
}
```