# Handling button click events from second page to determine outcomes in first page, Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, navigation, event-handling

I am using the Ionic Framework to build my app and I have used navPush and navPop to control navigation between two pages, and I have been able to send parameters from the first page to the second page using navPush. However, I am not really sure how to handle a button click that would not only pop back to the previous page (First Page) but also causes some features to run on the first page. For example, if you were to press the map button on the (Second Page), it will then show the polyline on the map page (First Page) between current location and the marker that was chosen. I already have the functionality for showing a polyline between a marker and current location, is there a way to pop back to the First Page with the marker chosen and a command to call a specific function?

SecondPage.ts:

```
  import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import { NavController, NavParams, Navbar} from 'ionic-angular';
  import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
  import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
  /**
  * Generated class for the ListPage page.
  *
  * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  * Ionic pages and navigation.
  */
  @Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html',
  })
  export class ListPage {
  @ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
  places: any = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private callNumber: CallNumber, private toast: Toast) {
    this.places = [];
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
      this.navCtrl.pop({animate: true, animation: "transition", direction: "down", duration: 300});
    };
    this.places = this.navParams.get('places');
    this.places.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a.distance.substring(0, a.distance.indexOf(' ')))
     - parseFloat(b.distance.substring(0, b.distance.indexOf(' ')))});
  }

  phoneDial(phone_number) {
    this.toast.show("Calling Number.", '3000', 'center');
    this.callNumber.callNumber(phone_number, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommands to use **Events** in `ionic-angular` module. And this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911611/ionic-update-a-components-variable-from-another-page-or-component/50914069#50914069) may will help you

Comment: Thank you this helped. I also found a good tutorial using this link: https://alligator.io/ionic/events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, here is a good link to a tutorial that helped me to figure it out: https://alligator.io/ionic/events/, I hope this helps others developing with the ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

The page (origin) you're calling ListPage, you have something like this...

openModal(atividade){
    let window = this.modalCtrl.create("L3E1AtivModalPage", {name: atividade.name, conteudo:atividade.conteudo, data:atividade.data, tipo:atividade.tipo, id:atividade.id, concluido:atividade.concluido});

You have to add something like this after...

```
window.onDidDismiss(dataRet=>{
    atividade.data = dataRet.data;
    atividade.name=dataRet.name
    atividade.conteudo=dataRet.conteudo
    atividade.tipo=dataRet.tipo
    atividade.concluido = dataRet.concluido
})
window.present();
```

*atividade* is the array I have on my origin page, so I receive the params the page had before dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function, example:

Main page

```
export class MainPage {
  dataFromOtherPage = null;

  callback = data => {
    this.dataFromOtherPage = data;
    console.log('data received from other page', this.dataFromOtherPage);
  };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  openOtherPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('OtherPage', {
      callback: this.callback
    });
  }
}
```

The other page:

```
export class OtherPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  goToPreviousPage() {
    this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => {
      this.navParams.get('callback')('This is some data');
    });
  }
}
```